# Does the Gmail add-on work in mobile browsers?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm unable to find any UI to open Gmail add-ons in my Safari browser on mobile.

I attempted to use Chrome on my mobile but couldn't find it in the UI either. However, in the native app, there is a UI option at the bottom of the email to open add-ons.

Comment: They do in my IOS Chrome.  You can load it from the App Store

Answer (score 0):

I finally found in the documentation that it doesn't work in mobile browsers
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PGBRX.png)